# UIBarButton in Navigation Controller's Toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am banging my head against a wall, thinking this should be simple, but I cannot figure it out.

I have an app, with multiple instances of the same Navigataion Controller class.  Is it possible to add code to said Navigation Controller class (in this case UIBarButtonItems for the toolbar) so that anything I do in that class will show up anywhere within that navigation controller?

I have added the following code, yet nothing shows up on the toolbar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *add = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, add, flexibleSpace];

[toolBar setItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing to fix it, is to build all of the items to go in the tool bar and then call from the NavigationController class:

```
self.topViewController.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: obj1, obj2, obj3, nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your call to `-arrayWithObjects:` you have forgotten to terminate the list with `nil`.

```
NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, add, flexibleSpace, nil];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithObjects:

Comment: And use NSArray *toolbarItems = @[flexibleSpace, add, flexibleSpace]; So you don't have to worry about stuff like that :))

Comment: And this is okay to add to the NavigationController class?  I have added it again, and still nothing is showing

Comment: Sorry, meant to say, I have made the changes suggested, and added again, and nothing is showing up.

Comment: Also let me add, that the final goal is just so that I don't have to build the same toolbar into each view...I assume that is possible, perhaps I'm not going about it the right way?